# Are the live connections dropped on azure while doing Blue Green deployment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I am deploying my java rest services on  Azure App services, I am trying to understand blue green  deployment on azure, I read this official blog on Azure Blue Green : 
[https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/blue-green-deployments-using-azure-traffic-manager/](https://%20https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/blue-green-deployments-using-azure-traffic-manager/)

I got the initial idea, but what if there are many live connections on Blue instance and new code is deployed on the green instance and after sanity testing, we swap blue with green. If there is any live connection on blue will it die or will it hold till it serves the meaning full response from the end service

From swap I a mean the control button called Swap available on Azure App services. My main concern will there be any data lost while swapping when there is a live connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existing requests will be terminated or impacted in any way. The article itself talks about how you gradually move traffic from one blue to green. It doesn't abruptly terminate the requests.

I think this part gives some confusion:

> we swap blue with green

The swapping is not a destructive operation where you kill one instance and start using another one. The swapping is just telling traffic manager to point to another IP. Requests pointing to the old IP are not impacted.

You can test this by creating an endpoint that holds a connection for a long time. Then while connection is held, click swap. Have logging to see what happened.

For App Service specifically, the documentation says this:

> The traffic redirection is seamless, and no requests are dropped because of swap operations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots

Comment: Hi Erndob thanks for the reply, I wanted to confirm is it our responsibility to gradually move traffic from Blue to Green?

Comment: And any suggestions on when should we delete the staging environment?

Comment: The AppService Swap doesn't move the traffic gradually. What you can do is control the traffic yourself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#route-traffic
There's kind of two different things here, one is the traffic manager as a service, and another is built-in swapping in app services.

Comment: As Erndob mentioned, if your requirement fits, you could route specific percentage (0 -100) of traffic to specific slots. Once the setting is saved, the specified percentage of clients is randomly routed to the non-production slot.  Also, The entire deployment slot swap workflow can be automated by configuring Auto Swap when pre-swap validation isn't needed. Note that after a swap, the slot with previously staged app now has the previous production app.